# Fix IP for Docker

Tags: docker

I have deploy a docker server for learning and testing proposes, I have start by installing portainer.

When I try access portainer from publica ip, I have noted that not have given, portainer use private ip..

```
error during connect: Get http://remote.host:2375/v1.29/info: dial tcp: lookup remote.host on 10.1.94.8:53: no such host
```

I have try accessing from public ip: myip:9000 but do not working

How can I change it?

Comment: did you try to connect via `localhost`? http://localhost:9000 from your browser?

Comment: I do not, It is installed on a scaleway server (remote)

Comment: can you try to `curl http://localhost:9000` from your server to see if you get anything?

Comment: how did you run the docker? could you share the command?

Comment: I have deploy a machine with pre installed docker

Comment: from http://portainer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html, seems like you can specify `--ip xx.xx.xx.xx`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you,

I have resolved it, by editing:

> /etc/resolv.conf

And change

> nameserver private ip to nameserver - public ip